# Getting Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: symfony, laravel-4

I'm sending a PUT request that handles input data and updates a record, but I get the above response. The problem doesn't seem to be the route, however, because if I do `dd($user)` after the `$user = User::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();` line, I get the object returned correctly.

Yet, when it comes time to validate it, it throws this error.

```
# routes
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'update']]);

# api call
PUT /users/2

# controller
public function update($id)
{

    $user = User::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();

    $input = Input::all();

    $this->userForm->validate($input);

    $user->fill($input)->save();

    return $user->toJson();

}

# userForm class

<?php namespace Olp\Forms;

use Laracasts\Validation\FormValidator;

class UserForm extends FormValidator {

    protected $rules = [
        'email'         => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'      => 'required',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
        'firstname'     => 'required',
        'lastname'      => 'required',
        'schoolname'    => 'required',
        'address1'      => 'required',
        'address2'      => 'required',
        'postcode'      => 'required',
        'city'          => 'required'
    ];
}
```

and in my UserController:

```
use Olp\Forms\UserForm;

class UsersController extends \BaseController {

    function __construct(UserForm $userForm)
    {
        $this->userForm = $userForm;
    }
```

Comment: BTW, you only need: `$user = User::findOrFail($id);`

Comment: So what happens here: `$this->userForm->validate($input);`? Can you include the code for the model function for this?

Comment: @hebron Thanks for the reply - I've added the relevant code for that part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Laravel guy, but a quick check on their documentation indicates that [Resource Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) support PUT in addition to other HTTP verbs.

I was not able to figure out how to add HTTP verb support to an arbitrary action, but [this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#implicit-controllers) indicates that you can name a controller action prefixed with the verb it responds to

```
public function putUpdate($id)
```

Comment: If he were using a `Route::controller` yes, but he is using a `Route:resource` which automatically defines the `update` with a `PUT` route. :)